# How to get the size of the entire X509 certificate

Tags: c, openssl, certificate, x509

I am reading a .crt certificate which I generate using openSSL. I have the certificate in my C program in a X509 file. I would like to know the size of the whole certificate that I have just read. How can this be there? Is there a specific function that returns the size of the certificate?

Thanks
Best Regards

Comment: Do you mean size of certificate in DER format? Or PEM? Or another?

Comment: I have the certificate in a file stored on the computer. I am reading it to a X509 structure. The X509 structure is read to PEM format with: PEM_read_BIO_X509_AUX. Also I will need to send the certificate over the network. should this goes on DER or PEM format? which one is more compact? Thanks

Comment: DER should be more compact, with its binary format, but honestly unless your sending oodles of them I doubt it will matter much.

Comment: ok, thanks. But do you know how I can programatically in C know the exact size of the certificate, the X509 in PEM format ?

Comment: Just convert it to PEM format and calculate, what's the problem here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For sending certificate over the network, I recommend using DER format. The reason is that PEM is Base64-encoded DER plus some additional text (prefix/suffix).

To estimate the size, you actually need to encode the certificate (this is DER):

```
size_t get_length(X509 *cer)
{
    int len;

    len = i2d_X509(cer, NULL);
    return len > 0 ? len : 0;
}
```

For PEM it is trickier:

```
unsigned char *data;
BIO *bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
PEM_write_bio_X509(bio, cer);
len = BIO_get_mem_data(bio, &data);
// here - data is a pointer to encoded data, len - length of data.

BIO_free(bio); // free _after_ you no longer need data
```

Comment: Thanks:) As I said I am reading the data from a PEM file and using it in my program. Do you know In case I want to use the DER format instead of the PEM, if I can just use openssl conversion from PEM to DER and instead of read the PEM file read the DER file and the program will work? Or I need to change all the code associated with reading the certificate, extract the public key, verify date and so on? Thank you so much:)

Comment: @moursika It depends. Really. `openssl` tool can make those conversions though.

Comment: I think you have a bug in the last line where you have BIO_free(data), it should be BIO_free(bio). I have checked and my certificate has 666bytes. Do you know if there is any way of generating very small certificates just only with the information I want? I was expecting to have something like 120bytes ou maybe 150 at most. Thanks

Comment: @moursika You are right. Fixed. If you use short string in certificate strings, it will be small. PEM can't be too small though.

Comment: in the BIO_get_mem_data(bio, &data) function, the data buffer has the data of the the certificate? What I mean is that if data is a buffer that contains the certificate ? Thanks

Comment: what I mean is that if I can send the buffer data over the network and if I will be able to recover the X509 back with that buffer. thanks